# What are the ASP.NET MVC 6 Features?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Can anybody tell me what are the new features available in ASP.NET MVC 6.0?
And what is the very nice feature which insist me to migrate my project MVC 5.0 to MVC 6.0?

Comment: 9 times out of 10 when I see a comment like the above I have come HERE from a simple Google search.

Comment: SO is going to moderate it's self out of existence at this rate

Comment: This is not a too broad question. It's not like MVC 6 has a ton of new features and we can't pick the top 5.

Comment: If you disagree with the moderators' decision then you could vote to re-open the question. I have.

Comment: I think ASP.NET MCV 6 moved to ASP.NET Core MVC 1

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This is the best list I found that answered a few of my questions:

http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc6/5R9E190514-Introduction-to-ASP.NET-vNext-and-MVC-6.html

Here is a summary of the 10 features they covered:

- Cloud optimized versions of MVC, Web API, Web Pages, SignalR, and EF
- MVC, Web API and Web Pages merged into one framework (MVC6)
- No dependency on System.Web (HttpContext object graph drops from ~30k/req to ~2k/req)
- New project extension `project.json` to list all dependencies and a `Startup` class that replaces global.asax
- Cloud ready by design. Session state and caching adjust behavior depending on hosting environment.
- Host agnostic
- True Side-by-side deployment. Just upload dependencies to the bin directory without affecting other apps on same server.
- Dependency injection built in
- Roslyn compiler for dynamic code compilation. Edit code and see changes without having to rebuild
- Open source and cross-platform (can work on Mono, Mac, Linux, etc)

Comment: To what are you referring as "Web Pages"?

Comment: I think they are referring to .cshtml/.vbhtml web pages (Razor)

Comment: Web Pages are html+Razor, and related to WebMatrix - simple dynamic pages like php, without a framework like MVC to back them up: "ASP.NET Web Pages focuses on adding dynamic (server-side) code and database access to HTML pages, and features simple and lightweight syntax." More here: http://www.asp.net/web-pages

Answer (score 15):

**The best featues in MVC6**

1. Asp MVC 6 added new cloud computing optimization system of MVC, web API, SignalR and entity framework.
2. Microsoft removed the dependency of system.web.dll from MVC 6 because it's so expensive. Typically it consumes 30K memory per request/response. Right now, in MVC 6 consume 2K memory per request response. It's too small memory consume.
3. The Microsoft make a bundle of MVC, Web API, WebPages, Signal, That bundle we called MVC 6.
4. Most of the problem solved using the Roslyn Compiler.
5. The ASP .Net vNext used the Roslyn Compiler, by using Roslyn compiler do not need to compile the application its compile automatically the application code.
6. The .Net vNext has the new project extension project.json. Basically project. json contains the all dependency dll of the application.
7. In MVC 5.1 and 5.2 supports to Enum and EnumHelper in razor views.
8. The .Net vNext is a cross platform and open source.

Comment: Will you please justify how .NET vNext is cross platform?

Comment: @AdityaBokade Bokade,For proof of how radically Microsoft has evolved, especially in terms of its approach to Cross platform,Refer this link http://www.infoworld.com/article/2608322/microsoft-net/microsoft-s-new-open-source-asp-net-can-run-on-linux--os-x.html

Comment: Is it only me or is this answer actually a copy-paste-and-break-the-grammar version (mostly) of the [answer by Sam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26243269)? Didn't mean to offend though, just pointing out what seems evident.